# form_for goes out of the input elements. Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

Wanted to create a forma and run UJS on it. However got an issue: the form tag is outside of the input fields? How is that possible?

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="email_notification[secondary]" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input id="email_notification_secondary_254" name="email_notification[secondary]" type="checkbox" value="1">    
  </td>
</tr>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/email_notifications/255" class="edit_email_notification" id="edit_email_notification_255" method="post"></form>
```

So this is how I have setup the form, please correct me if I'm wrong

```
  <% @setting.email_notifications.each do |en| %>
    <%= form_for en do |u| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= en.notification.name %></td>
        <td><%= u.check_box :primary, { :id => "email_notification_primary_" + en.id.to_s } %></td>
        <td><%= u.check_box :secondary, { :id => "email_notification_secondary_" + en.id.to_s } %></td>
        <td><%= u.select :interval, @days, { :id => "email_notification_secondary_" + en.id.to_s } if en.notification.required_intervals? %></td>
        <td><%= u.submit %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

The main issue is, when I'm trying to grab element by class and then type, nothing is selected, and that's expectable as the form element sits outside of the input element.

```
$('.email_notification input[type=checkbox]')
```

**UPDATE**

If that make any change I'm using `twitter bootstrap` tables

Comment: I have one query where is your en.notification.name goes in html

Comment: what do you mean? it's just a name, just a string that outputs the name of the Notification object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your table inside the form element, looks like :

```
<table>
  <% @setting.email_notifications.each do |en| %>
  <tr><td>
     <%= form_for en do |u| %>
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td><%= en.notification.name %></td>
          <td><%= u.check_box :primary, { :id => "email_notification_primary_" + en.id.to_s } %></td>
          <td><%= u.check_box :secondary, { :id => "email_notification_secondary_" + en.id.to_s } %></td>
          <td><%= u.select :interval, @days, { :id => "email_notification_secondary_" + en.id.to_s } if en.notification.required_intervals? %></td>
          <td><%= u.submit %></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
     <% end %>
  </td></tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

You can see different on <kbd>[jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucwjU/3/)</kbd>

But just suggesting : Build your form without tables if possible.